# why does div move when z index is set?

Tags: html, css

I read that z-index positive and greater than other divs should stack the div on top of others with lower z-index.  Why does the identified div move, and how do I prevent this?   This question different from asking about display:none vs visibility because the z-index should allow for layering divs from an x, y 2-dimension plane to a third dimension, z.

http://jsfiddle.net/9RxLM/5832/

```js
var mouseX;
var mouseY;
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  mouseX = e.pageX + 20;
  mouseY = e.pageY - 20;
});


$(".dimoption").click(function() {

  var $maxdim = $("#msgmaxdim");
  $maxdim.css({
    'top': mouseY,
    'left': mouseX
  }).fadeIn('slow');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $maxdim.fadeOut('slow');
  }, 3000);

});
```

```css
.description {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="dimoption">Text
<div id="msgmaxdim" class="description">Popup overlay</div>
<div id="othercontent">
  Why does this div move?
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't have to do with the z-index. Read [What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Comment: The source here in the text is not the same as the fiddle (well, not the latest revision anyway, maybe one of the 5831 earlier revisions...)

Comment: @MrLister I corrected the jsfiddle.

Comment: @4castle I understand the difference between visibility and hiddden, but the z order is higher on the element added, and should not effect the positioning of other elements.

Comment: @sammarcow No, 4castle is saying that the z-index is not the problem. Rather, the changed `display` value is, causing the repositioning. Anyway, the fiddle is still the same... which revision of the fiddle did you want to show?

Comment: @MrLister ok, but how do I achieve the desired effect of overlaying multiple divs with a popup?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question that has been marked as a duplicate. He isn't talking about display vs visibility. He is asking why, when visible, it is moving the other div. This is an issue of the overlay not being positioned to absolute.

Comment: @A.Sharma The question is: "why does it move?". It moves because `display: none` hides and removes the previous element from the flow, unlike `visibility: hidden` which would have only hid it. Another question would be: "how to make a visible element out-of-flow?". The answer would be absolute (including fixed) positioning, and (partially) floats.

Comment: @Oriol I guess it is open for interpretation then, and the interpretation depends on the OP's underlying question. The answer provides solutions to both though so it's all good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `z-index` isn't affecting it. It's `display: none` which is messing with the positioning of the other elements. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone).

If you want there to be a blank space where the `div` would be when it's not hidden, use

```
visibility: hidden;
```

If you want the elements to overlap when the `div` is visible, use

```
position: absolute;
```

Comment: Thank you, the position set to absolute was the error.